# MySQL select between dates leaving blank

Tags: mysql, date, between

I'm trying to do a search.

And there is an input startDate and another one finalDate.

but the person might not type a start or final date or neither...

im trying to use:

```
(data BETWEEN ".$startDate." AND ".$finalDate.")
```

Leaving it blank it's not working, unless i put a start and final dates.

I wanted that even if the person doesn't type the dates, it keeps searching for the rest.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==edited as per request==

put it before sql query:

```
if(empty($finalDate))
$where = "(data >= ".$startDate.")";
else if(empty($startDate))
$where =  "(data <= ".$finaltDate.")";   
else
$where = "(data BETWEEN ".$startDate." AND ".$finalDate.")";
```

and change

```
(data BETWEEN ".$startDate." AND ".$finalDate.")
```

with

```
".$where."
```

Comment: but what about if the person types only the finalDate?? would i need another if? or there is a better case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can probably  do something like this.

```
CASE WHEN  StartDate IS NOT NULL 
 AND              EndDate IS NOT NULL 
THEN Date
 BETWEEN  StartDate AND EndDate;
```

This is just an illustration of how it can be done , give it a shot

Comment: I typed this in my Iphone sorry for the poor styling etc